# Loggin a user out of a database on browser close PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, browser, logout

I have seen MANY questions on this before online in many places, however, out of about 30 forums and whatnot, NONE of them have had the solution I need, and that includes stackoverflow. If anyone could help me find a reliable solution, it would be greatly appreciated, so thanks in advance!

I'm going to explain my site and situation with as much detail as possible  in order to help any who want to help answer my questions. Here is my situation:

I have a website and I use PHP and MySQL. My website is a "private" organization site. In order to allow people access to the site, I send new members of our organization and invite code. The user then visits the website, and the index.php file simply contains a form for logging in as well as a link to the registration pages. New members click the "Register Here" link to begin registration. The first registration page asks for the user's last name and invite code which are checked against a database to make sure that person is on the list and has not yet registered. If they pass the check, they are taken to the next page in which they enter required information (username & password, email address, etc.) as well as some optional information (phone, bio, etc.). If the user creates a valid username and password and has all required fields filled out, their information is stored in a database. Passwords are all salted and hashed properly and securely, so there is no problem there, and the whole registration process works as it should. After registering, the user is taken back to index.php where they can now log into using the username and password they just created. This works as well; when the user logs in, their username and password are checked against the database, and if successful, the user is logged in. When the user is logged in, an ONLINE value in the database is set from False to True. The user is now logged in and can use the site as it is intended. On my site, there is a column that lists users that are currently online (based on the ONLINE value from the database). When the user clicks the "Log Out" button which is located on every page of the site, the logout.php script is run, ending the session and setting the ONLINE value back to False. This all works fine and dandy, however, the problem comes when the user closes the browser without logging out first. This is where I have seen many different "solutions" various places on the internet. I am going to explain why they won't work and why I need a better solution.

The answers I see most often involve some sort of session timeout or destroying sessions, which is irrelevant because of the fact that the session already does, in fact, end when the user closes the browser, but that has no effect on telling other users whether or not that person is currently online. When the session ends, the database won't be updated, which causes a problem due to the fact that a user can only be logged in from a single instance. If a user attempts to log in while their ONLINE value is already set to TRUE, they aren't allowed to log in.

I have also seen suggestions of using a "Last Seen" value instead of an online value, and if a user hasn't had any activity within the past x amount of minutes, log the user out. This won't work, however, for two reasons. 1) That script still has to be running somewhere in order for that to work, meaning another user must be logged in for that to work. That basically means that, if using this method, if a user closes their browser or if they loose connection, they won't be able to log back in until another user logs in. With my organization being a small, locally based organization as it is, there are likely to be many times in which there are no users online. Also, even if another user is logged in, the user whose connection was lost still won't be able to log back in until after x amount of minutes has passed, so if the user accidentally closed their browser and wanted to log back in immediately, they simply wouldn't be able to.

A less frequent solution I came across involved using the onBeforeUnload JavaScript function, but those most definitely will not work due to the fact that those would trigger any time a user clicked on a link or on the "Back" and "Forward" buttons. Also, if the user has JavaScript disabled in their browser, this will not work at all.

The last thing I have seen involves while loops and the connection_aborted function, and this is the only one that seems like it could work, yet I have not seen a very clear description of how this should work, and after spending months experimenting with it, I still have not come up with a reliable solution.

In many forums, I have seen people say that "it's not possible," but that can't be the case considering there are sites that do it somehow. I have tested and experimented with this on several sites. On a site that has users such as Facebook or any forum website, there is a list of "online" users, and in the case that a user closed their browser, their name would no longer appear on the list, so it is possible, even if it can only be achieved through some obscure method. So, if anyone knows of a solution, I would greatly appreciate if you could share some of your wisdom on this subject!

Comment: Your best bet is to simply incorporate an inactivity timeout.  Log the person off if there has been no activity in the last 10 or 15 (or whatever) minutes.  I don't buy your argument that this won't work; a running web application is a running web application.

Comment: Maybe far fetched, or too much of an effort to implement but you could check out socket.io which provides a pretty reliable transmission method through HTTP to the client and can easily detect a socket disconnect.

Comment: You can design your client-side browser code to send a message ending the user session when the user navigates away from a page. But, your intuition to the contrary notwithstanding, you *cannot* guarantee such a message will always be sent by web app client code. What if the user pulls the battery from her laptop when your window is open? You need a timeout strategy as a backup for session cancellation.

Comment: @mobius suggests using persistent connections.  Guess how the TCP stack detects the loss of persistent connections?  Timeout.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am aware of all of that, but that is not the problem. If the user closes the browser or loses connection, the timeout will check the time since the last log in, and that's fine. The thing is, if a user's browser crashes, they'll likely want to relaunch the browser and log back in immediately, but they wouldn't be able to log back in immediately due to the fact that the timeout would likely be longer than the 15 seconds it would take for them to relaunch the browser and navigate back to the site, causing the user to have to wait for the timeout to expire before logging back in.

Comment: Put a session token in a browser cookie.  If the cookie exists, and 15 minutes hasn't elapsed, let them reopen the browser still logged in.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Using session cookies seems to a good route. After a few hours of studying and editing, I think I've got things the way I want them. Thanks.

Comment: @OllieJones To be more specific, socket.io uses a number of technologies to provide with a web-socket like interface, where web-sockets are not available. So it's not entirely TCP, yet it detects the disconnection by timeouts, but the most important benefit is that it does work and is easy to implement without having to worry with the details per se.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Heartbeat mechanism in javascript.
this method would start sending an ajax call to your webmethod on timely basis use.

```
setInterval(function(){
sendPulse();
},30000);


sendPulse(){

var varUserID = userID;//any unique user identifier that can be found on server side
$.ajax({

    url: "Default.php/updateUserStatus",
    UserID: varUserID,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (mydata) {

        //alert("pulse sent");
    }
    });
   }
```

On server side, you must have a method with same name and case sensitive parameter. the should be static and marked as webmethod. in this method save the current time for the user. you should have a mechanism to know what users have very old pulse, do this check when a user tries to do something or performs any operation.  I have implemented this approach and works very well.

Answer (score 0):

That's the answer: persistent connection between client and server. For this, you will need a TCP connection, like websockets nowadays, or a flash old duplex connection. From here on, TCP takes care of noticing you when someone connects or disconnects. What you got to do is a websocket server (for example) who just traks connections (push and pop from an array), and also a way to respond to a "get_users_online" message. You can access your user's session (read only) via the websocket server, and then see if the user is logged-in (and in this way, you can store his nickname in session, access further from websocket server), see if he is admin (session->is_admin).

Pretty simple, I would say.

Here is the library I've been using: http://socketo.me/ . It uses a library for decoding symfony2 sessions, but for simple applications, you don't need decoding (symfony2 applications encodes sessions, so the websocket server has to decode them).

Big note: Sessions has to be stored externally (not in file system /tmp) like a ORM or NoSql.

Either way, escuse me, but I have to say that that the "Last time" seen is super okey. Most of the sites rely on this. You understood something wrong, you don't need to have a living server for checking "Last time" always, when you request /admin.php?users_online=1 , you make a query where "Last seen > NOW() - 5 minutes" (won't work written like that), so you can even get rid of the "ONLINE" "OFFLINE" field.

I suggest using a websocket approach, it's fun. :)

Good luck!

Comment: This seems like something good for me to look into. I'll try this. Thanks.